# How to encode a URL in an AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to submit URLs that I'm building dynamically in my AngularJS controller code, and then encoding using encodeURIComponent()

Here's a URL example built out dynamically (prior to encoding, and will not submit via Fiddler):

```
http://localhost:49479/api/aggr?sid=f68f52614800393fdbef22cc55a7d3d0fea10e655fff6e7573ca&kri=[CDSStress A]:[USD 10Y X -1.25],[CDSStress A]:[USD 1Y X 1.25]&aggrFunc=SUM([CDSStress A]:[USD 10Y X -1.25]),SUM([CDSStress A]:[USD 1Y X 1.25])&dim=Counterparty
```

Same URL, manually encoded with %20 (which does submit to API layer via Fiddler):

```
http://localhost:49479/api/aggr?sid=f68f52614800393fdbef22cc55a7d3d0fea10e655fff6e7573ca&kri=[CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%201.25],[CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%20-1.25]&aggrFunc=SUM([CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%201.25]),SUM([CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%20-1.25])&dim=Counterparty
```

However, encoding via encodeURIComponent() does not submit to my API layer via Fiddler. Here's the coded URL:

```
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A49479%2Fapi%2Faggr%3Fsid%3Df68f52614800393fdbef22cc55a7d3d0fea10e655fff6e7573ca%26kri%3D%5BCDSStress%20A%5D%3A%5BUSD%201Y%20X%201.25%5D%2C%5BCDSStress%20A%5D%3A%5BUSD%201Y%20X%20-1.25%5D%26aggrFunc%3DSUM(%5BCDSStress%20A%5D%3A%5BUSD%201Y%20X%201.25%5D)%2CSUM(%5BCDSStress%20A%5D%3A%5BUSD%201Y%20X%20-1.25%5D)%26dim%3DCounterparty
```

and my angular controller code which builds out the URL and submit to datacontext layer :

```
function sendAggrRequest(kriList, aggrFunc, dim) {

        var results = [];
        var rageVars = $rootScope.rageSessionVars;
        var url = "http://" + rageVars.domainName + ":" + rageVars.port + "/api/aggr?sid=" + rageVars.sessionID +
                "&kri=" + kriList + "&aggrFunc=" + aggrFunc + "&dim=" + dim;            

        url="http://localhost:49479/api/aggr?sid=a74b9822cf5e0e75b0d8ff0c25981a573606893150348d6cad80&kri=[CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%201.25],[CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%20-1.25]&aggrFunc=SUM([CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%201.25]),SUM([CDSStress%20A]:[USD%201Y%20X%20-1.25])&dim=Counterparty"
        datacontext.sendAggrRequestToServer(encodeURIComponent(url)).then(function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'FAIL') {
                if (data.messages.length > 0) {
                    logErr("Error retrieving KRI list: " + data.messages[0]);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                results = data.data;
            }                
        });
 }
```

If you can provide some advice on the best way to encode URLs, that would be great.

thank you.

Bob

Comment: did you try encodeURI(uri)? or may be you can just regex replace space with %20

Comment: I did try encodeURI() but it appeared to be truncating it. turns out I was wrong. encodeURI() does appear to be working. Perhaps make it your answer since you've helped me to examine this further. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
encodeURI(uri)?
```

or may be you can just `regex replace` `space` with `%20`

Comment: encodeURI() appears to be doing something strange to the URL. A regex replace with %20 is at least working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had no issues using encodeURIComponent inside AngularJS:

```
var params = $location.search();
var someThingEncoded = encodeURIComponent(params.someThing);
```

If things are funky, you may want to try also $log.log.  For example, encodeURI may not work for a url segment, but encodeURIComponent still may, so you can try logging both to console and compare.